# How to install CentOS 7 on another machine without using a physical installation media like USB or DVD?

Tags: centos, networking, usb, system-installation, nfs

Currently I have two machines on the same network:

1. Windows 8.1 machine
2. CentOS 7 machine

I want to reinstall the 2nd machine with a clean CentOS 7 install.

That machine is situated at another place where I can't reach now. But I can ssh into it.

Since I don't have a direct physical access to it, it is not possible to use a bootable USB or DVD (ISO burned) to initialize the CentOS installation in it. Also, it is a server without GUI.

How can I do the installation process successfully in this scenario? Can someone help me with the proper step-by-step guidelines?

I found this option:

- network installation (still need a bootable media to start the installation): [Performing a CentOS Network Installation - Techotopia](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Performing_a_CentOS_Network_Installation)

But couldn't find a suitable one.

Is it possible to mount a CentOS 7 ISO image in my Windows machine, and access that mounted ISO for installation in CentOS? I thought I can use it as NFS source for installation.

In that case (or in any case), how can I start the installation from the CentOS machine (without using any bootable media like USB)?

Comment: Hello, could you please edit your question and add why solutions like PXE boot aren't applicable here?

Comment: @Panki Actually i'm completely new in this topic, so i couldn't understand how it works with 2 machines with different OS. Will edit the question now.

Comment: Excuse me if these are stupid questions: What is DC? Can you ask someone else (with physical access) to put a bootable media into the server for this purpose?

Comment: @sudodus DC means data center. I edited the question anyway. Also, Inserting a bootable media is not possible in the current situation. That's the problem!

Comment: Would it be possible to modify the current drive by adding a menuentry to [boot from an iso file](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot) in a partition, and to boot that way into the Centos installer? If you want to install a new system, it should be into another partition, not the one where you have the iso file. -- You cannot just copy from the Ubuntu help page, the boot commands will probably be different for Centos, but you should be able to find the correct details via the internet. -- However, I am *not* sure that you could access a live system directly via ssh.

Comment: @sudodus okay. I will check it.

Comment: Do you have KVM access to this unit? Does it have a network management interface (also known as BMC)? Or are you limited to ssh/scp?

Comment: @llywrch Yes, i have a kvm access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have KVM access to the machine, you have two fairly straightforward solutions.

The first -- & easiest -- is to determine if your KVM setup supports mounting a USB or DVD remotely. (Read the Fine Manual to determine this.) I know one of the products I have used over the years, which is manufactured by Raritan, supports this. Because one thinks KVM as only a remote tool to access the monitor, keyboard & mouse, the fact it also supports the USB protocol is easily overlooked.

The drawback with this solution is, of course, bandwidth latency. If you have only a 1Mb connection to this machine, it will take a while to transfer the install data to the target.

The second solution, which is a little more difficult, is to use your KVM access to implement @jsbillings suggestion. Put the image somewhere the target CentOS system can see it (e.g., the Windows machine), & use the image file there. Although the commands might be a bit tricky if you aren't an experienced Linux SysAdmin, you won't have the same bandwidth issue the first option poses. But having KVM access means you can actually monitor the install, & you have a means to access the system if the install encounters an unforeseen problem.

Pick the option you are most comfortable with, & give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a boot entry from the ‘vmlinuz’ and ‘initrd.img’ found here:

http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/os/x86_64/images/pxeboot/

Add a kernel parameter with “inst.repo=http://server/path” that points to a URL of the installation media (or pick a centos mirror). If you need to assign networking on boot (not dhcp) you can add [additional parameters](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en_us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/chap-anaconda-boot-options).

For an headless install (I.e. no access to console), you can choose between an automated install through a kickstart, or set up VNC remote console. See [the RHEL instructions](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/installation_guide/chap-headless-installations).